# Strapi beta - update other tables from other controller

Tags: controller, strapi

I have 2 content types "products and stock", "stock" needs to be updated on "products" update. I'm trying to update "stock" from the "products" controller.

Currently i'm following instructions under - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers

An error occurs when i try to update "stock":

```
error TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');
const stock             = require('../../stock/controllers/Stock');

module.exports = {
    async update(ctx) {

      let test = await stock.update(ctx.params, ctx.request.body);

      let entity;
      entity = await strapi.services.products.update(
         ctx.params,
         ctx.request.body
      )
    },
}
```

I have also tried the following from within my product controller, resulting with the same error:

```
let stock = await strapi.services.stocks.update(
         ctx.params,
         ctx.request.body
      )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello! To make sure to give you the exact answer to your question, can you detail exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically, on product update i need to run business logic which affects other content-types (table).

I would like my business logic to perform a number of different actions and that includes create, updating, deleting data from other content-types (tables).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you trigger the `services` instead of the `controllers`.

Because on the code you wrote, you are not passing the right params.

And `controller` functions have to be call by a route and not by another controller.

Comment: Thank you man. For my own reference and others, i'm assuming you mean the following? https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/services.html#concept

Comment: Yap! with `strapi.api.stock.services.stock.update(ctx.params, ctx.request.body)`